# Java seems to be skipping my else statement; random also seems to only be 0 or 20

Tags: java

Been struggling with this for a while. Can't seem to figure out if it's something in this file or something in my main file that's causing it. Here's the code for my number guessing game:

```
package pkgjava.program;

import java.util.*;

public class NumberGame {
    int decision;

    void numberGame() {

        do {
            // Number game instructions
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Welcome to the number game! Enter a number between 0 and 20 below."
                + " The program will tell you if you need to enter a larger or smaller number. Let's begin!");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

            // Case 1 Variables
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            Random rand = new Random();
            int computerNumber = rand.nextInt(20);
            while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Invalid entry! Please enter a number: ");
                input.next();
            }
            int userNumber = input.nextInt();
            int tries = 1;

            if (userNumber > 20 || userNumber < 0) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Error: Number out of scope.\nTry again: ");
                while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Invalid entry! Please enter a number: ");
                    input.next();
                }
                userNumber = input.nextInt();
            } // IF user enters a smaller number...
            else if (userNumber < computerNumber) {
                do {
                    if (userNumber > 20 || userNumber < 0) {
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("Error: Number out of scope.\nTry again: ");
                        while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
                            System.out.println();
                            System.out.println("Invalid entry! Please enter a number: ");
                            input.next();
                        }
                        userNumber = input.nextInt();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("Nope! The number you entered is smaller than mine. Try again: ");
                        while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid entry! Please enter a number: ");
                            input.next();
                        }
                        userNumber = input.nextInt();
                        tries++;
                    }
                } while (userNumber < computerNumber);
            } // IF user enters a larger number
            else if (userNumber > computerNumber) {
                do {
                    if (userNumber > 20 || userNumber < 0) {
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("Error: Number out of scope.\nTry again: ");
                        while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
                            System.out.println();
                            System.out.println("Invalid entry! Please enter a number: ");
                            input.next();
                        }
                        userNumber = input.nextInt();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("Nope! Think smaller. Try again: ");
                        while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
                            System.out.println();
                            System.out.println("Invalid entry! Please enter a number: ");
                            input.next();
                        }
                        userNumber = input.nextInt();
                        tries++;
                    }
                } while (userNumber > computerNumber);
            } // IF user guesses correctly
            else {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("You got it! My number was: " + computerNumber + "!" + " It took you " + tries
                    + " tries. Would you like to play again? 1. Yes / 2. No");
                while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid command! Please enter the number corresponding to your menu choice: ");
                    input.next();
                }
                this.decision = input.nextInt();
                   if (decision != 1) {
                       Main.check++;   
                   }
                   else {
                      decision = 0;
                   }
            } 
        } while(decision == 0);
    }
}
```

Here's my main class:

```
/**
 * @projectname Simple Java Program
 * @author Joseph Kiebler
 */
package pkgjava.program;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    static int check = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Menu menu1 = new Menu();
        NumberGame num1 = new NumberGame();
        ConvertFraction conv1 = new ConvertFraction();
        ChatSim sim1 = new ChatSim();
        Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the program! Please consider the menu "
            + "options and enter the corresponding number below.");
        System.out.println();
        menu1.mainMenu();
        while (!userIn.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Invalid entry! Try again: ");
            userIn.next();
        }
        int choice = userIn.nextInt();

        switch (choice) {

            case 1:
                num1.numberGame();
                break;

            case 2:
                sim1.chatSim();
                break;

            case 4:
                conv1.convertFraction();
                break;

            case 5:
                System.out.println("Exiting program...");
                System.exit(0);
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid selection! Try again: ");
                userIn.nextInt();
        }
        while (check != 0) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the program! Please consider the menu "
                + "options and enter the corresponding number below.");
            System.out.println();
            menu1.mainMenu();
            while (!userIn.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Invalid entry! Try again: ");
                userIn.next();
            }
            choice = userIn.nextInt();

            switch (choice) {

                case 1:
                    num1.numberGame();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    sim1.chatSim();
                    break;

                case 4:
                    conv1.convertFraction();
                    break;

                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Exiting program...");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid selection! Try again: ");
                    userIn.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting program...");
    }
}
```

I know the methods I've used aren't the most efficient, but this is my first programming language and I've already been doing it for two weeks, so... go easy on me :P. Anyhow, is there anything conflicting in the two classes that would cause the errors described above?

Comment: Where exactly are the problems happening?

Comment: Have you tried debugging.  There is too much code here, but I guess (as always) the error is with the `scanner.next()`

Comment: This is way to much code to display a problem about an else statement and a variable value. Trim it down and make an example program.

Comment: Well remove 20 from rand.nextInt(20), this actually binds the value from 0 to 20.

Comment: Where is the else and the random that is having problems?

Comment: WHICH `else` statement?  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] and edit your post accordingly.  You have to tell us what the problem is (specifically), identify all important bits, and tell us what you've tried.

Comment: Apologies, all. I had actually realized that I was being very vague and was trying to figure out the best way to point to the exact location of the issues. The else statement in question starts near the end of the first codeblock. There's a line above it that says "//IF the user guesses correctly". Line 86.

The random is towards the beginning defined in the "Case 1 Variables" block. I've debugged and get nada.

Comment: Some clarification on the issue with the random:

I actually want the random to be limited to values between 0 and 20. The problem is that it's only randomizing to the values 0 and 20, nothing in between.

Comment: @Ruindotdmg Please edit in clarification in the question, rather than posting them in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you will only go into ONE of the cases in an if-else statement like that one.

Your program is assuming that once you go into one of the cases, say (userNumber < computerNumber), that once a user inputs the correct number, it will then hit that else statement. Unfortunately it doesn't work that way. In an if-else block like that, you will only be choosing one of the cases, and then after that it will skip to whatever comes after the else statement. It doesn't re-evaluate the cases once it's already chosen one. The next step is to loop back to the beginning of the program, so that's what it does once it finishes evaluating the "else-if" statement.

What you will need to do is make sure you loop back to the if-statement, rather than the beginning of the program. A possible way to do this would be a boolean flag that says when you've chosen the correct answer, and a while loop that tests for this value. That way you can set the flag to true when the correct answer is found, and if its not, you can loop back to the beginning of the if-statement.

Comment: Thanks so much! Got everything working flawlessly now (and fixing the else-if statements fixed the randomizer)!

Apologies to everyone for the crappy format of my question and code.